# Listbox using a data template and dynamic data loading based on selection Enumeration Error

Tags: wpf, listbox, observablecollection, enumeration, inotifypropertychanged

To anyone that can help or show me a better way. I have tried to do this with an observable collection, a list based on a custom class, global/non-global collections, using the listbox's itemssource, synclocking, and finally emptying and manually entering in items.

It tends to work fine, but every once in a while I get the error "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute." which seems to occur at System.Collections.ArrayList.ArrayListEnumeratorSimple.MoveNext()

I have tried a few different things over the past couple of weeks and I am able to avoid it sometimes, but then I can reproduce it in a different area.

Essentially, I have three listboxes Parent, Current, Children. These have captioned images in them.
When an Image is selected the images in the Parent, Current, and Children empty and reload based on the selected image.

I've written it in vb, but I can convert it to C# if that will help. The code has been changed many times and so the latest one has a lot of commented code in it. Any Help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Anything to simplify it, get it to work, or performance enhancements would be great.

Imagine the code in triplicate. The code is nearly identical with the exception of names.

```
<Page.Resources>

    <CollectionViewSource
          Source="{Binding Source={x:Static Application.Current}, Path=CurrentList}"   
          x:Key="CurrentList" />

</Page.Resources>

<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="2" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"    PanningMode="VerticalOnly" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                  >
                <ListBox Name="CurrentListbox" VerticalAlignment ="Stretch" Margin=" 8" Background="Transparent" 
                          Height="Auto"   BorderThickness="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                         ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentList}">
                    <ListBox.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                            <EventSetter Event="ListBoxItem.Selected" Handler="CurrentListBoxItem_Selected" HandledEventsToo="false"/>
                </Style>
                        </ListBox.Resources>
                    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderBrush="#FF0000AC" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ThumbnailBorder}">
                        <!--<Viewbox MaxWidth ="100" >-->
                        <StackPanel>

                            <Grid>
                                <Border  Name="ItemBorder" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ThumbnailInnerBorder}"/>
                                <Image Name="PersonImage" MaxHeight ="200" MaxWidth ="200" Source="{Binding ProfileImagePath}"
                                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
                                    <Image.OpacityMask>
                                        <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=ItemBorder}"/>
                                    </Image.OpacityMask>
                                </Image>
                            </Grid>
                            <Viewbox MaxWidth ="190" Margin="5,0,5,0" MaxHeight="15">
                                <TextBlock Name="Person" Text="{Binding ProfileName}" Tag="{Binding UserID}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                            </Viewbox>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <!--</Viewbox>-->
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

                    </ListBox>

    </ScrollViewer>
```

The Collection is stored in a global Variable and populated using a SQlCe Command.

```
Public Shared CurrentPeopleList As New CollectionViewSource
Public Shared Current_People_List As New ObservableCollection(Of Currents)()

Public Shared Property CurrentList() As ObservableCollection(Of Currents)
    Get
        Return Current_People_List
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As ObservableCollection(Of Currents))
        Current_People_List = value

    End Set
End Property
```

The Custom Class of Currents:

```
Public Class Currents
Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

Private ProfileNameValue As String

Private UserIDValue As Integer

Private ProfileImagePathValue As String

Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
```

#Region "Properties Getters and Setters"
    Public Property ProfileName() As String
        Get
            Return Me.ProfileNameValue
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Me.ProfileNameValue = value
            OnPropertyChanged("ProfileName")
        End Set
    End Property

```
Public Property UserID() As Integer
    Get
        Return Me.UserIDValue
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        If value < 0 Then
            Throw New ArgumentException("User ID must be greater than 0 ")
        End If
        Me.UserIDValue = value
        OnPropertyChanged("UserID")
    End Set
End Property

Public Property ProfileImagePath() As String
    Get
        Return Me.ProfileImagePathValue
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        Me.ProfileImagePathValue = RelativeProgramPath() & "Media\Pictures\" & value
        OnPropertyChanged("ProfileImagePath")
    End Set
End Property


#End Region

Public Sub New(ByVal UserID As Integer, ByVal ProfileName As String, ByVal ProfileImagePath As String)
    Me.ProfileNameValue = ProfileName
    Me.UserIDValue = UserID
    Me.ProfileImagePathValue = If(ProfileImagePath Like "pack://*", ProfileImagePath, RelativeProgramPath() & "Media\Pictures\" & ProfileImagePath)

End Sub

Protected Sub OnPropertyChanged(ByVal name As String)
    RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(name))
End Sub

End Class
```

Finally, the way these are populated is by using a common function

```
 Private Sub Reload(ByVal CurrentID As Integer)
        Try


        Try
            ParentList = Nothing
            CurrentList = Nothing
            ChildrenList = Nothing
        Catch
        End Try
        Try
            Me.ParentListbox.ItemsSource = Nothing
            Me.CurrentListbox.ItemsSource = Nothing
            Me.ChildListbox.ItemsSource = Nothing
        Catch
        End Try
        Try

            CurrentPersonID = CurrentID
            'Load the Images Based on the people.
            Dim Ch = Load_Children_People(CurrentID)
            Dim C = Load_Current_People(CurrentID)
            Dim P = Load_Parent_People(CurrentID)

            ParentList = If(P.Count > 0, P, Nothing)
            CurrentList = If(C.Count > 0, C, Nothing)
            ChildrenList = If(Ch.Count > 0, Ch, Nothing)
        Catch
        End Try
        Try

            If ParentList IsNot Nothing Then _
                Me.ParentListbox.ItemsSource = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(ParentList)

            If CurrentList IsNot Nothing Then _
                Me.CurrentListbox.ItemsSource = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(CurrentList)
            If ChildrenList IsNot Nothing Then _
                Me.ChildListbox.ItemsSource = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(ChildrenList)
        Catch
        End Try



    Catch
    End Try
    'For some reason this will not work without a pause. Not sure why.
    'FIXME Remove Pause Delay When able. 
    'Thread.Sleep(200)
End Sub
```

I used a lot of try-catch's to attempt to catch the error, but have been unsuccessful thus far. My suspicion is that the error occurs during a UI thread that I cannot seem to pin down.  As I mentioned earlier. any assistance would be great.

Comment: Just a thought for now (will try to look later at more detail) - try not setting the properties to `Nothing` - instead, clear the collections with code like `ParentList.Clear()` and just reload them with updated data during your various `Load()` processes. I seem to remember a weird situation where setting the properties to `Nothing` would sometimes screw up the bindings and make thing go wonky. See if that helps. If not, I'll try to dig in a bit deeper...

Comment: I tried the method that you suggest and i still receive the same error. I tried setting it against the observable collection, then against the list itself using the clear method, but I still end up with the same program. I have found that varying degrees of a pause with prevent the error from occurring, but as the number of items in the list increases so too must the delay. I stopped around 5 seconds. Realistically, no one will wait longer than a half a second for this.